# How can you read just the first word of every line of file using python?

Tags: python, file, parsing

What's the most efficient way to read just the first word of every line in a large text file? Should I use `split`? Is there a more efficient way? Can I just read one word and discard the line and go to the next line?
Right now I'm using this:

```
for line in f:
    dct[line.split(None, 1)[0]] = dct.get(line.split(None, 1)[0], 0) + 1
```

Comment: Coming here we assume you've made some kind of effort to solve your own issue, if you did - please show us your code, if not, start by trying and post a more specific question. Good luck!

Comment: What did you tried ? and wan you add an overview of your input file ?

Answer (score 4):

To maximize efficiency use

```
line.split(" ",1)[0]
```

Split on first occurrence therefore saves time

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(' ')[0])
```

Where `file.txt` is the file you want to read. You can also use:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r') 
for line in f:
        print(line.split(' ')[0])
```

- `f.readline()` returns the line
- `.split(' ')` creates a list with each word as an element
- `[0]` selects the 0th element

Putting that as I put it maximizes efficiency by not losing time assigning values to variables. Although it is not too much.

Comment: f.readline().split(' ')[0] should be line.split(' ')[0]. Since you are already in a for loop

Comment: Thanks. It's true, I don't know what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine what a "line" is, you have to read until you find a newline. You correctly identified that `split()` is the way to go if you want to use only the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `somestring.split(" ")`